# Old votes are not visible in timeline after revoting

Tags: bug, voting, timeline

I voted up [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519812/3240681) over one year ago, but I did it before last edit on the answer occurs. Today I revoke my vote up (just for test) and vote up again. For now [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34519812/timeline) says that answer has never been voted up before today:

> [image: timeline]

This is somewhat confising. Possible solution is to add "revoke" event to timeline.